# why we create DNS forward lookup and reverse lookup files in /var/named/?

Tags: networking, server, dns

I was looking for DNS Configuration Tutorial and I found this one [Setup DNS Server](https://www.linuxtechi.com/setup-bind-server-centos-8-rhel-8/)

I got all the steps except one step, why he created the forward and reverse lookup zone files in /var/named/ ?

Comment: Hello. The site you have linked is to a discontinued product called Centos. Why that was done on that OS may not be the same way you would configure it here on Ubuntu. What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: In Ubuntu we don't. Suggest [this reference](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/service-domain-name-service-dns)

Answer (score 2):

You're using an outdated guide for a dead operating system called CentOS.

If you simply just want a DNS server that does lookups, you can simply just install `bind9` packaging and get the DNS server part there.

If you want to serve zone data from the system, then you just create the forward zones.  You don't *need* reverse lookup zones in `/var/named/` unless you want reverse lookups for IPs.

The reason `/var/named/` is used in CentOS is because the package is called `named` there.

However, in Ubuntu systems, the package is called `bind9` and the main directory root for the BIND nameserver is `/var/cache/bind` as defined in `/etc/bind/named.conf.options` in a default setup.  Which is where you would put your forward/reverse lookup zones (even if you have any number of subdirectory structures in that directory to organize).  Outside of that location, AppArmor has rules in place to confine BIND9 and prevent badness, so outside of those directories your files for zones might not be read/written properly and as such you should always use `/var/cache/bind` as the base directory root for your zones, etc. that BIND9 might write back to (especially if you use `nsupdate` for dynamic DNS assignment on the zones).

---

Full disclosure: I'm working on a how-to for getting a BIND9 server properly configured and secured for DNS server functions of serving forward and reverse zones, and will post that on my blog and then link back here in comments.  However, I don't have the cycles *today* to finish writing that post.

Comment: I have only ever known to put the forward and reverse zone files in `/etc/bind` as per the [Ubuntu serverguide](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/service-domain-name-service-dns).

Comment: @DougSmythies yeah I would say that guide needs some updates, because if you look at the apparmor confinement rules it only has **read** access in `/etc/bind` for the zone files.  If you use any zones that receive updates via `nsupdate` connections it can't create the journal files there and can't writeback because of the AppArmor confinement.  Which is why `/var/cache/bind` is actually the only directory it can read/write to fully.  Either that or AppArmor rules need revised.

Comment: Thanks. I do see a note to that effect. I don't use updates on my server and so never noticed.